# How to load java properties file and use in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, properties-file

I want to store the Spark arguments such as input file, output file into a Java property files and pass that file into Spark Driver. I'm using spark-submit for submitting the job but couldn't find a parameter to pass the properties file. Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: have you tired this option: --properties-file FILE      Path to a file from which to load extra properties

Answer (score 37, accepted):

here i found one solution:

**props file** : (mypropsfile.conf)   // **note: prefix your key with "spark." else props will be ignored.**

```
spark.myapp.input /input/path
spark.myapp.output /output/path
```

**launch**

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --properties-file  mypropsfile.conf
```

**how to call in code** :( inside code)

```
sc.getConf.get("spark.driver.host")  // localhost
sc.getConf.get("spark.myapp.input")       // /input/path
sc.getConf.get("spark.myapp.output")      // /output/path
```

Comment: @ramisetty.vijay : the file extension should be .conf or we could use .properties also?

Comment: it worked for .properties file also. but format inside should be spark.my.key  \t myvalue

Comment: How can I add multiple properties file? Preferably in a directory.

Comment: Warning, the use of --properties-file does overwrite any previous defined spark-defaults.conf (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) so it may be necessary to create your own merged version.

Comment: Using --properties-file can override any settings defined in spark-defaults.conf which can be different for each environment. Do you need to ensure that the properties file is a merged version?

Answer (score 8):

The previous answer's approach has the restriction that is every property should start with `spark` in property file-

e.g.

> spark.myapp.input
>  spark.myapp.output

If suppose you have a property which doesn't start with `spark`:

**job.property:**

> app.name=xyz

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --properties-file  job.property
```

**Spark will ignore all properties doesn't have prefix `spark.` with message:**

> Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: app.name=test

How I manage property file in application's driver and executor:

```
${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit --files job.properties
```

**Java code to access the cache file (job.properties)**:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

//Load file to propert object using HDFS FileSystem
String fileName = SparkFiles.get("job.properties")
Configuration hdfsConf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(hdfsConf);

//THe file name contains absolute path of file
FSDataInputStream is = fs.open(new Path(fileName));

// Or use java IO
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/res/example.xls");

Properties prop = new Properties();
//load properties
prop.load(is)
//retrieve properties
prop.getProperty("app.name");
```

**If you have environment specific properties `(dev/test/prod)` then supply APP_ENV custom java environment variable in `spark-submit`:**

```
${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit --conf \
"spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-DAPP_ENV=dev spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-DAPP_ENV=dev" \
--properties-file  dev.property
```

**Replace your driver or executor code:**

```
//Load file to propert object using HDFS FileSystem
String fileName = SparkFiles.get(System.getProperty("APP_ENV")+".properties")
```

Comment: How did it got connected to HDFS filesystem?

Comment: In my case, I was using HDFS. You may use java io to read properties file as well.