# How do I pass an environment variable into spark-submit

Tags: configuration, apache-spark

I am using apache-spark 1.2.0 and would like my user's Linux environment variable `$MY_KEY` to be made available to my Java job when executed using `master=local`

In Java land this could be passed in using a `-D` parameter, but I cannot get this recognized when my driver is launched using `spark-submit`

I have tried adding this to `conf/spark-defaults.conf`, but spark will not resolve the environment variable $MY_KEY when it executes my Java job (I see this in my logs)

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions  -Dkeyfile="${MY_KEY}"
```

I have tried adding the same as an argument when calling spark-submit, but this doesn't work either.

The same problem with adding it to `conf/spark-env.sh`

The only way I have got this to work is by editing the `bin/spark-submit` script directly which defeats the purpose of having it read from the existing environment variable and will get overwritten when I upgrade spark.

So it looks to me like spark-submit ignores your current users' environment variables and only allows a restricted subset of variables to be defined in it's conf files. Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115881/how-to-load-java-properties-file-and-use-in-spark/31118770#31118770

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately a jar file I am working with is expecting the variable to be available to `System.getProperty("keyfile")`

Comment: @Brad did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Hi @Eugen, no I didn't. I solved my problem by having the value defined in an external property file that my application loads. I can't comment on whether more recent versions of Spark have the same behaviour.

Comment: Same behavior with recent versions :/ Thanks for the update.