# Load properties file in Spark classpath during spark-submit execution

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-atlas

I'm installing the Spark Atlas Connector in a spark submit script (https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/spark-atlas-connector)
Due to security restrictions, I can't put the atlas-application.properties in the spark/conf repository.

I used the two options in the spark-submit :

```
--driver-class-path  "spark.driver.extraClassPath=hdfs:///directory_to_properties_files" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=hdfs:///directory_to_properties_files" \
```

When I launch the spark-submit, I encounter this issue :

```
20/07/20 11:32:50 INFO ApplicationProperties: Looking for atlas-application.properties in classpath
20/07/20 11:32:50 INFO ApplicationProperties: Looking for /atlas-application.properties in classpath
20/07/20 11:32:50 INFO ApplicationProperties: Loading atlas-application.properties from null
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [loading properties with spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365552/loading-properties-with-spark-submit)

Comment: properties files are already available in HDFS, Instead of passing params or config in spark-submit.. write code to read data from hdfs inside your spark code

Answer (score 0):

Please find CDP Atals Configuration article.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-pass-atlas-application-properties-configuration-file/ta-p/322158

Client Mode:

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-java-options="-Datlas.conf=/tmp/" /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/spark-examples*.jar 10
```

Cluster Mode:

```
sudo -u spark spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --files /tmp/atlas-application.properties --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Datlas.conf=./" /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/spark-examples*.jar 10
```