# How to pass parameters / properties to Spark jobs with spark-submit

Tags: java, apache-spark, command-line

I am running a Spark job implemented in Java using `spark-submit`. I would like to pass parameters to this job - e.g. a `time-start` and `time-end` parameter to parametrize the Spark application.

What I tried was using the

```
--conf key=value
```

option of the `spark-submit` script, but when I try to read the parameter in my Spark job with

```
sparkContext.getConf().get("key")
```

I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key
```

Furthermore, when I use `sparkContext.getConf().toDebugString()` I don't see my value in the output.

**Further Notice** Since I want to submit my Spark Job via the Spark REST Service I cannot use an OS Environment Variable or the like.

Is there any possibility to implement this?

Comment: `key=value` in the example supposed to be `spark` configuration property or your "custom" property?

Comment: I want to have a "custom" property, accessible from within my Spark job (a Java application)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass -D parameter or environment variable to Spark job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166667/how-to-pass-d-parameter-or-environment-variable-to-spark-job)

Comment: Checkout this post- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115881/how-to-load-java-properties-file-and-use-in-spark

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you want to use your custom properties you need to place your properties after `application.jar` in `spark-submit` (like in spark example `[application-arguments]` should be your properties. `--conf` should be spark configuration properties.

> --conf: Arbitrary **Spark configuration property** in key=value format. For values that contain spaces wrap “key=value” in quotes (as shown).

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class> \
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # options
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments] <--- here our app arguments
```

so when you do: `spark-submit .... app.jar key=value` in `main` method you will get `args[0]` as `key=value`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String firstArg = args[0]; //eq. to key=value
}
```

but you want to use `key value` pairs you need to parse somehow your `app arguments`.

You can check [Apache Commons CLI library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) or some alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Spark configuration will use only keys in the `spark` namespace. If you don't won't to use independent configuration tool you can try:

```
--conf spark.mynamespace.key=value
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters like this:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class $classname \
  --master XXX \
  --deploy-mode XXX \
  --conf XXX \
  $application-jar --**key1** $**value** --**key2** $**value2**\
```

Make sure to replace `key1`, `key2` and `value` with proper values.